# laravel form validation not working correctly with x-show alpine js

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, alpine.js

I have a situation where I am showing/hiding form fields based on the input of a previous field. For example:

```php
 <x-forms.select @change="bussingRequired = $event.target.value" label="Bussing Required" name="bussing_required" required >
   <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
   <option value="No">No</option>
</x-forms.select>
```

```php
<div class="col-span-12" x-show="bussingRequired == 'Yes'">
   <div>
      <!-- show another required field -->
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem with this is x-show only hides the element with CSS and the field still exists in the DOM. Since the hidden field is required, frontend validation fails.

My question is what is the better way to handle this? Is there a way to completely remove the element from the DOM with alpineJS? Is there a way to modify the frontend validation in laravel with something like a `required_if` like we have in the backend?

Comment: how about `x-if` ? instead of `x-show` ?

Comment: of course, I'm not sure why I didn't think of this. Must of been a long day. It is working. Thanks!